# jquery:html form inputs not working on touch device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, mobile

i have a problem with form

my form not working on tablet & mobile tested on samsung SM-T211

it work fine on pc browsers like firefox - chrome

what is the problem , please

here's the problem demo

```
http://th-elsharqya.com/new/admin/
```

and here's the jquery code for the form

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
            $( 'form' ).submit( function(){
               var o = $(this) ;
               var l = o.attr('action') ;

               $.post( l , o.serialize() , function(d){
                     if( d == 1 || d == '1' ) {
                        $('#ajaxresult').attr('class' , 'success').text('تم تسجيل الدخول بنجاح') ;
                        o.attr('class' , 'form-signin animated s2 flash') ;
                        setTimeout( function(){
                             $(window.location).attr("href", "index.php")  ;
                        } , 3000 ) ;
                     } else if( d == -1 || d == '-1' ) {
                        $('#ajaxresult').attr('class' , 'warning').text('حقل اسم الدخول فارغ') ;
                        o.removeAttr('class').attr('class' , 'form-signin animated s1').delay(100).addClass('shake') ;
                     } else if( d == -2 || d == '-2' ) {
                        $('#ajaxresult').attr('class' , 'warning').text('حقل كلمه السر فارغ') ;
                        o.removeAttr('class').attr('class' , 'form-signin animated s1').delay(100).addClass('shake') ;
                     } else {
                        $('#ajaxresult').attr('class' , 'error').text('عفوا بيانات الدخول خاطئه') ;
                        o.removeAttr('class').attr('class' , 'form-signin animated s1').delay(100).addClass('shake') ;
                        console.log( d ) ;
                     }
               } ) ;

               return false ;
            } ) ;

            setTimeout(function(){
               $('#logo img').removeClass('rotateInDownRight').addClass('wiggle');
               $('#logo h1').removeClass('fadeInLeftBig').addClass('swing loop s3');
            } , 2000);

            $('#logo img').hover(function(){
              $(this).removeClass('wiggle').addClass('shake') ;
            },function(){
              $(this).removeClass('shake');
            });

            $('#ajaxresult').click(function(){
              $(this).addClass('hide') ;
            })


    } ) ;
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using jquery, you may need to use jquery UI touch punch library. "***jQuery UI Touch Punch is a small hack that enables the use of touch events on sites using the jQuery UI user interface library.***"

It can be found here http://touchpunch.furf.com/